# convert subset of vector<uint8_t> to int

Tags: c++, stl

I am having trouble figuring out how to convert an vector of hex values to a decimal long int.

```
    vector<uint8_t>v;

    v.push_back(0x02);
    v.push_back(0x08);
    v.push_back(0x00);
    v.push_back(0x04);
    v.push_back(0x60);
    v.push_back(0x50);
    v.push_back(0x58);
    v.push_back(0x4E);
    v.push_back(0x01);
    v.push_back(0x80);

//How would I achieve this:
    long time =  0x00046050584E0180; //1,231,798,102,000,000
```

How would I get elements 2-9 for the vector v into an long int like represented above with the long 'time'.

Thanks!

Comment: In most systems an `int` won't hold that many bits... ;)

Comment: modified to be long int...

Comment: Seems something wrong, your example is missing first 2 bytes (0x02 and 0x08)

Comment: @PSIAlt I didn't elaborate.  I only care about the last 8.  In this scenario 0x02 is tag, and 0x08 is the length of the value.  This is just one field if many that I am parsing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic principler here would be:

```
int x = 0; 
for(uint8_t i : v)
{
   x <<= 8; 
   x |= i;
}
```

Comment: The original code uses unsigned integers whose upper bytes are filled with zero on upcast.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense.

Comment: Any decent compiler would have optimized that away anyway... :-]

Answer (score 1):

Not tested:

```
int time = 0;
for (int i:v) time = time << 8 + i;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `std::vector` contains its data in a memory vector, you can use a pointer cast, e. g.:

```
vector<uint8_t> v;
assert(v.size() >= 2 + sizeof(long)/sizeof(uint8_t));
long time = *reinterpret_cast<const long*>(&v[2]);
```

Make sure, the vector contains enough data though, and beware of different endianness types.

Answer (score 1):

You can of course do this algorithmically with the appropriately defined function:

```
long long f( long long acc, unsigned char val )
{
   return ( acc << 8 ) + val;
}
```

the value is computed by:

```
#include <numeric>

long long result = std::accumulate( v.begin() + 2, v.end(), 0ll, f );
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is as below and I've already tested. You may have a try.

```
long long res = 0;
for (int i = 2; i < 10; ++i)
    res = (res << 8) + v[i];
```